# jQuery show/hide elements with specific attribute

Tags: jquery

I have simple scenario:

```
<div someAttr='1'></div>
<div someAttr='2'></div>
<div someAttr='3'></div>
<div someAttr='4'></div>
...
```

How to

1) hide that elements which `someAttr` is not `1` ?

2) restore previous action ? To show all elements with `someAttr` attribute

Comment: Use an attribute selector?

Comment: Yes, I personally find this answer a bit of a "let's just post something on SO before 'googleing' it". And it is a duplicate... [the other is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075466)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery get value of "target" attribute if it matches some string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075466/jquery-get-value-of-target-attribute-if-it-matches-some-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide them:

```
var not = '1';
$("[someAttr]:not([someAttr='" + not + "'])").hide();

// or, if you prefer a less-generic function:
$("[someAttr]:not([someAttr='1'])").hide();
```

Then, to show all of them again, you just do:

```
$("[someAttr]").show();

// or, to show only the one hidden before (because you could be hiding
//     the others for some other reasons...
$("[someAttr='1']").show();

//again, using the more generic solution:
$("[someAttr='" + not + "'])").show();
```

This should do what you want to.

As some additional info, I don't reccomend (and other people will agree, too) using custom attributes. The old browsers just strip them, so this might not work...
So, what I'd do is to set it as a data-attribute, so `data-someAttr`. (Everything is identic in the code, just add the `data-` before each `someAttr`)

Does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

To hide,

```
$('div[someAttr!="1"]').hide();
```

To Show,

```
$('div[someAttr]').show();
```

Fiddle : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b2c2S/)

Comment: I didn't know that selector was valid, but it's nice to see it is. Saves a lot of code. And I don't understand the down vote, seems perfect for me...

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use jQuery's `toggle()` method (hide/show) and specify your selector:

```
// hide/show all but 1
$('div[someAttr!="1"]').toggle();

// hide/show 1
$('div[someAttr="1"]').toggle();
```

jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/